# Identifying the boundary of a Möbius band to a single point

Tags: algebraic-topology

The Möbius band has the polygonal presentation $$\langle a,b,c \vert abcb\rangle$$

[image]

Now I am asked to identify the boundary of the Möbius band to a single point. How do I represent this using polygonal presentations? Is that even possible?

I am aware of the same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203933/collapsing-the-boundary-of-a-m%C3%B6bius-strip-to-a-point) and my intuition was also $\mathbb{P}^2$ but I want to prove this using presentations rather than just words. I mean it is a general question, how to present the identification to a single point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your square diagram, pinch sides $a$ and $c$ to points, leaving the "digon" whose sides are the $b$'s with indicated identification. That's a well-known representation of the real projective plane.

Comment: Nice, thank you. I wondered if there are any intermediate steps, but apparently not. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of shrinking the boundary to a point you can add a 2-cell (you can't do this in 3-space.) The following gives some relevant pictures:http://www.groupoids.org.uk/outofline/motion.html#motion